What is the inner product for Dirac operator on Riemannian manifold
I don't know the background topics, and I'm trying to figure out   -What is the inner product in this setting : M is a Riemannian manifold of even dimension.
SM → M is a complex spinor bundle on M endowed with its invariantly defined indefinite inner product (·, ·).  Dirac operator acting on sections of SM is  D : C∞(M; SM) → C∞(M; SM)   .
Dirac operator is formally self adjoint, However I don't understand what is the relevant inner product ....
Specificaly ,in Euclidean $R^4$ ,where spinors are complex valued 4-vectors:
Is it the standard inner product $$(u,v)_x= u^\dagger v $$ ?
On the other hand, Physics uses this inner product,  which has some invariance property in Minkowski space :
$$(u,v)_x=u^\dagger \gamma^0 v.$$
Thanks !

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
